CSS changes with language - what could be possible causes?
I'm editing a website on Joomla 4.4.3 with someone's custom template, based on T4. I noticed that some of CSS is missing when I switch to German language. For example:
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .nav-breakpoint-lg.oc-desktop .t4-offcanvas-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -12px;
  }
}

It is part of css/template.css file. I searched the entire template directory and didn't find any other references to that definition.
I don't see any relation of CSS to language anywhere in the panel, Googling things like "Joomla language specific CSS" or "Joomla language stylesheet" doesn't yield any useful results.
The CSS is combined and cached by a plugin called JHC Optimize. Turning it off temporarily doesn't help.
What am I missing? Where could this be defined? What code, definition or place to look for?

You should mention the file where this CSS is located (assuming it's not inline) and the template you're using.

Oops, forgot about the file. The template is custom. Based on some T4 template.

Here's also thje website if it helps: https://www.lenkraddesign.eu/ And an example of the element is the hamburger icon on the sticky bar.
